# Process video frame by frame with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I want to be able to process a video frame by frame with NodeJS. I've looked at fluent-ffmpeg, but I don't think it supports processing the video frame by frame.

Comment: You'll have to decode the video into individual frames (using FFmpeg... its command line binary is fine), read these frames in Node.js, do whatever you want to do them, and then re-encode a video from these frames.  This is an intensive process.

Comment: I saw your other question concerning frame differences. May I ask why you need to use Node.js? You could use something like the open source computer vision library instead http://opencv.org/.

Comment: If you need to use Nodejs for video processing you can use OpenCV wrapper for Nodejs (https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenCV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv) node package will allow reading and processing of video.
See examples.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opencv this package have literally nothing. why would you suggest a blank security holder repo? i don't think you get money from clicking